# Is the notification of other new answers whilst typing an answer broken?

Tags: support, answers, notifications

A couple of times recently, I've started answering a question and by the time I have posted my answer, another has appeared.

In the past, I have received a notification at the top of the screen offering to show the new answer(s), but this no longer seems to be happening.

Is this a bug, a deliberate act on the part of the site's owners or is it me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The notification takes some time to appear, it's not instant. So if you posted it less than a minute after, it's possible that it didn't have the time to notify you.

If it was a longer time like 5 minutes, then it seems more like a bug indeed.

Comment: I think it was a few minutes, but the times have been rounded to hours no so I'm not usre. If I notice it again I'll make a note of the time delay etc.

Comment: @Neal FYI: if you hover your mouse of the time stamps like "3 hours ago" you should get a tool-tip pop telling you the exact time.

Comment: @neal it's definitely working; the interval is 45 seconds